# Python Django - How to support Socket and APIs both

Tags: python, django, sockets

I am using python 3 and Django 1.9 and frontend is android.

I have to provide 2 connections one is via API so that user can use UI and send the his/her details to backend; second, socket connection for receiving Hardware details, failure logs and sending updates to app.

Below is my Socket server.

```
import socket, ssl, json
from threading import Thread, active_count
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn 
#from serializers import create_log_entry

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread): 

    def __init__(self,ip,port,conn): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port 
        self.conn = conn
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port), active_count() )

    def run(self):
        connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(self.conn,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="/home/ubuntu/workspace/logs/server.crt",
                                 keyfile="/home/ubuntu/workspace/logs/server.key")
        while True : 
            data = connstream.read()
            print ("Server received data:", data)
            if data != b"" : data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
            else:
                print("Exiting loop")
                break
            print ("Server received data:", data)
            #create_log_entry(data)
            connstream.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))  # echo 

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0' 
TCP_PORT = 2005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Usually 1024, but we need quick response 

def socket_server():
    tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
    tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
    threads = [] 

    while True: 
        tcpServer.listen(4) 
        print ("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...") 
        (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept() 
        newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn) 
        newthread.start() 
        threads.append(newthread) 

    for t in threads: 
        t.join() 

socket_server()
```

But it is threaded and listen to particular port. I am calling `socket_server()` in a serializer file to start the server. This server use a method in serializer file which create entry in MongoDB.

Now when I start Django, it will stop at this method call and I cannot use the APIs as server is midway booted.

What configuration I need to do in Django so that both works?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Django Channels.

Per the documentation:

> Channels is a project that takes Django and extends its abilities beyond HTTP - to handle WebSockets, chat protocols, IoT protocols, and more.

You install it and configure it just as any other application.  The only differences are that instead of creating new views or api calls and mapping them to your urls.py file you create new consumers and map them to a new **routing.py** file.

Consumers are little functions responsible for "consuming" events (e.g. connect, disconnect, receive message...)

It's currently installable as:

```
pip install -U channels
```

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I highly recommend following this tutorial to get yourself going:

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html

And here's the documentation for it:

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: How will that help me in using sockets?

Comment: can you please answer my questions?

Comment: You're attempting to configure a persistent TCP connection with your socket_server.  The channels application provides you the framework to achieve this task.  With this in place your client can create a persistent TCP connection along with your API calls.  Is this not what you were looking to do?